# Calling Class Functions on Regular Objects vs. Pointer Objects

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, instantiation

Why (and when) should I call class methods on pointers instead of just good ol' objects?

For example, given a class called "Car", I instantiate a normal object, then I instantiate another object but as a pointer this time. The output is the same, I just want to know what is the difference and why should I use one over the other?

Clarification: when SHOULD I create a pointer and use the class functions on that pointer, and when SHOULD I not do that?

```
class Car
{
private:
    string Name;
public:
    Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    void getInfo()
    {
        cout << "The car name is: " << Name << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Example 1 -- calling getInfo() on a normal object:
    Car car("BMW");
    car.getInfo();

    // Example 2 -- calling getInfo() on a pointer object:
    Car* carPtr = &car;
    carPtr->getInfo();
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have no choice in this matter. When you have a "regular object" your only option is to call a "class function" on this "regular object". When you have a pointer your only option is to call a "class function" on this pointer. C++ does not automatically change one to the other, on a whim. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Let me clarify my question: I know that if I have a regular object, don't have an option to use class function on a pointer, because it's not a pointer... and vice versa. My question is, when SHOULD I create a pointer and use the class functions on that pointer, and when SHOULD I not do that?

Comment: I would suggest a finding a quality source to learn C++ from. It will teach you about this.

Comment: You should not clarify your question by adding comments, but [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @Taekahn I am currently learning from a quality source. Just a question that I'm curious about.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But, again, pointers are not things that are purely optional, and can be used anytime one feels like using them. Pointers have specific use cases, and when a use case calls for a pointer, well, there are no other alternatives. Similarly, if there's no need to use a pointer it should not be used. There is a very common malady that affects a lot of people who are learning C++. It's called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Pointers are an essential tool but they should be used only when they are needed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah I see! So using pointers does not provide any objective benefits (such as program efficiency), rather they provide a specific toolkit to be used to solve problems that require their use only? Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: I would agree with this statement.

Comment: Pointers have several purposes, but none of those purposes are related to whether member functions are going to be called.  The calling of a member function should have no bearing on whether a pointer is being used.

Comment: Exactly the insight I was looking for. Thank you guys!

Comment: Also, when people say "pointers" in modern C++, they're talking about smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Raw pointers (`Car*`) are an ancient feature originating in C, and the answer to when those should be used is: almost never.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I disagree. Smart pointers are smart pointers, and raw pointers are raw pointers. Raw pointers can be very reasonably used as long as the whole project keeps to the promise that every raw pointer is non-owning (i.e. is just an observer). And no, `std::weak_ptr` is not a substitute for this use case, because it enforces shared ownership semantics, which may be not desireable. It all falls down to clear definition of what raw pointer is and what it isn't. As long as raw pointer is never owning, it's perfectly fine to use one.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I can understand that sentiment. Personally, I've been burned too many times by new programmers who use them sloppily, so my inclination is to ban them entirely and use `const&` for borrowed values. But your viewpoint is entirely fair too. Perhaps my previous comment was a bit brash in its extremity.

Answer (score 1):

> then I instantiate another object but as a pointer this time

That's actually not what your example does:

```
Car* carPtr = &car;
```

That code doesn't instantiate (i.e. create a new instance of) `Car`, it just gives you a pointer to `car`, the instance of `Car` that you created previously. So you have only one instance of `Car`, but two variables through which you can access it: `car`, of type `Car`; and `carPtr`, of type `Car *`.

So, one case where you might choose to use a pointer to an object is when you want to access an object that already exists.

Another case is when you want to create an object that should exist beyond the scope of the code that creates it. If you put code like:

```
Car volvo = Car("Volvo");
```

in a function, for example, `volvo` will be a local variable in that function, and it will be destroyed as soon as the function returns. If you want your object to live longer than that, you'd allocate it dynamically using `new`:

```
Car *volvoPtr = new Car("Volvo");
```

Now when the function returns, `volvoPtr` will go out of scope, but the object that it points to will still exist until you `delete` it. You can return the pointer (or better, a reference) from the function, or you could do something with it inside the function (like adding it to a larger graph of objects).